# How to not let terminal display anything?

Tags: c, console, embedded, terminal

environment: embedded system, linux, c.

Third party modules and my own modules will print information on terminal/console by using printf(). How can I forbid those information being shown on terminal/console? (notice that I cannot comment those printf() since some are in third party modules) Can I set the terminal to a certain mode so that nothing is shown? (something similar to system("stty sane"), maybe?) or do i need to use ioctl()? Please help me...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

If you want not to see the output when your run the program, you can redirect its output like this:

```
./program > /dev/null
```

`/dev/null` is a special device that eats up everything you feed it (like a black hole). `>` redirects the output (of `stdout`) to a file. Redirecting the output to `/dev/null` means everything is written to `/dev/null` and that doesn't do anything with it, therefore you effectively throw out your output.

If you want to do it in the program itself, you can call `freopen` and you can reopen `stdout` to `/dev/null`, getting the same effect. Like this:

```
freopen("/dev/null", "w", stdout);
```

**Sidenote**: To redirect `stderr`, instead of `>` you can use `2>` and with `freopen`, of course you reopen `stderr`. It's not such a good idea to redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` though, although it maybe helpful to redirect it to a file.

If you want to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr`, you can redirect `stderr` to `stdout` and `stdout` to `/dev/null` like this:

```
./program > /dev/null 2>&1
```

(note the order of redirection)

Comment: thanks Shahbaz. But there are multiple programs/processes running on the device, I have no way to do that. That's why i am thinking if I can do something with the terminal directly so that nothing will be shown

Comment: So you mean, you don't have access to the code, and you are not the one running them in command line?

Comment: It sounds like if you were able to do that, you wouldn't see anything, not even the shell itself on the screen, which makes shell almost useless. So I doubt such a thing would exist.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. Like I said, it doesn't make much sense either, and I suggest you try another approach (for example push whoever is running those programs to simply redirect their outputs.) Note that if you are using a library that is verbose like this, you can still `freopen` in your `main` and when you link to that library and execute, there wouldn't be a porblem

Comment: The reason that I want to do this is that I don't want hackers to see any output information should they manage to connect a console to our device. please help, anyone??

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the debug port? If so, you can rebuild the kernel to not have a debug port, or at least disable it.

If you are talking about the shell - that does not make any sense, right? If the shell is disabled, how do you access your device? As Shahbaz says, it's not likely to exist. A better option is to prevent user access to the shell.

Maybe you could explain more about what exactly you are trying to do, and how your device works, or at least how it is accessed.

**Update:**

Ok - our board has a web interface, we use that (password protected) to enable/disable the ssh server that is connected to the debug port. Sounds like that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. yes i am talking about connecting pc to device console via serial connection. we as developer use this to debug our program, but a hacker can also connect to the device through the same port. So i want to be able to turn on and off the shell - it will be on when developer or system admin want to access it, but if a hacker connect to it, we will show no information to him.